# Cloud Load Balancing HTTPS redirect not working for specific host

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

In my load balancer I have 6 hosts, in all hosts but one the HTTPS redirect works perfectly. I tried every configuration possible and read every docs that Google provides (concepts, how-to guides, reference), like https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#setting_up_the_http_load_balancer to no avail...

What drives me crazy is that in the same `url-map` there is a host, whose HTTPS redirect works 100%, which is an "identical" copy of the one that doesn't work. This is my `url-map` with the two hosts isolated:

```yaml
defaultUrlRedirect:
  httpsRedirect: true
  redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
  stripQuery: false

hostRules:
 - hosts:
   # I'm not using an actual record for this particular host, the following two are real
 - app.rocketseat.dev
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-staging
 - hosts:
 - app.rocketseat.com.br
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-production
 - hosts:
 - umbriel.rocketseat.dev
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-umbriel


pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client-staging
  name: path-matcher-staging
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /api/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendServices/app-staging
  - paths:
    - /*
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client-staging
  - paths:
    - /admin
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /index.html
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/admin-client-staging
  - paths:
    - /admin/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/admin-client-staging
  - paths:
    - /h
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /index.html
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/hubble-client-staging
  - paths:
    - /h/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/hubble-client-staging
  - paths:
    - /favicon.ico
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /favicon.png
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client-staging


- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client
  name: path-matcher-production
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /api/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendServices/app
  - paths:
    - /*
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client
  - paths:
    - /admin
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /index.html
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/admin-client
  - paths:
    - /admin/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/admin-client
  - paths:
    - /h
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /index.html
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/hubble-client
  - paths:
    - /h/*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/hubble-client
  - paths:
    - /favicon.ico
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /favicon.png
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/backendBuckets/student-client
```

`http://app.rocketseat.dev/api/hello` returns:

```
{
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
    "statusDetails": "response_sent_by_backend"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "http_load_balancer",
    "labels": {
      "backend_service_name": "app-staging",
      "forwarding_rule_name": "app-forwarding-rule-2",
      "target_proxy_name": "app-target-https-proxy",
      "url_map_name": "app-url-map"
    }
  },
  "severity": "INFO"
}
```

`http://app.rocketseat.com.br/api/hello` returns

```
{
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
    "statusDetails": "response_sent_by_backend"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "http_load_balancer",
    "labels": {
      "backend_service_name": "app",
      "forwarding_rule_name": "app-forwarding-rule",
      "target_proxy_name": "app-target-http-proxy",
      "url_map_name": "app-url-map"
    }
  },
  "severity": "INFO"
}
```

I thought, maybe it could be some difference in backend service/bucket configuration, but they're also identical.

---

Additional output:

```
# gcloud compute url-maps describe app-http-url-map

defaultUrlRedirect:
  httpsRedirect: true
  redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
kind: compute#urlMap
name: app-http-url-map
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/urlMaps/app-http-url-map

---
# gcloud compute target-http-proxies describe app-target-http-proxy

kind: compute#targetHttpProxy
name: app-target-http-proxy
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/targetHttpProxies/app-target-http-proxy
urlMap: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/urlMaps/app-url-map

---
# gcloud compute target-https-proxies describe app-target-https-proxy

kind: compute#targetHttpsProxy
name: app-target-https-proxy
quicOverride: NONE
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/targetHttpsProxies/app-target-https-proxy
sslCertificates:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/xesque
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/europa
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/umbriel
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/flexbalancer
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/dev
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/sslCertificates/app
urlMap: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/urlMaps/app-url-map
```

Comment: Do you see any [error logs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#viewing_logs) on stackdriver?

Comment: @Mahboob None, sadly. Before creating this question I tried to compare the logs between the two hosts but the only difference was target proxies and forwarding rules: `.dev` => HTTPS and `.com.br` => HTTP.

Comment: Have you created a [HTTP url-map](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#setting_up_the_http_load_balancer) that does not  reference any backend service but only the HTTPS url map?

Could you also provide the results of these commands:


`gcloud compute url-maps describe app-url-map`

`gcloud compute url-maps describe{http url-map}`

`gcloud compute target-http-proxies describe app-target-http-proxy`

`gcloud compute target-http-proxies describe app-target-https-proxy`

Comment: @RaynelA.S I added the requested outputs. How can I reference the HTTPS url-map in my HTTP url-map? Following the steps in that guide results in no redirect, only a Google 404 error... Can you shed some light on why I need to setup a HTTP url-map when every other host do redirect just fine with a single url-map with HTTP/HTTPS target proxies? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up realizing that the problem was not with the host itself, but that the HTTPS redirect in my URL map only worked for domains from **Google Domains**. I tried to migrate the rest of the domains to the same DNS provider/service (**Google Cloud DNS**) but the redirect still didn't work. Some sort of lower-level HTTP redirect or maybe an integration between GCP and Google Domains? I don't know, I've never seen anything like that.

Once again, I tried to follow the HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect [example](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect). Again, it didn't work, if you follow through the example you'll always encounter a 404 error while accessing the HTTP URL.

But if you add a host rule with a path matcher like this to the URL map:

```yaml
defaultUrlRedirect:
  httpsRedirect: true
  redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
  stripQuery: false
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - '*'
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-wildcard
kind: compute#urlMap
name: app-http-url-map
pathMatchers:
- defaultUrlRedirect:
    httpsRedirect: true
    redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
    stripQuery: false
  name: path-matcher-wildcard
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/global/urlMaps/app-http-url-map
```

All your traffic will be redirected to HTTPS. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you kindly provided and in similar scenarios, it could be that you have configured one URL map for the HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection. Whereas, you need to create an HTTP URL map that its only purpose is to redirect traffic to the HTTPS URL map where you configure the hostRules and pathMatchers.

In this [exemple](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#load-balancer), "web-map-http" is created solely to redirect HTTP traffic to the HTTPS URL map "web-map-https" and "web-map-https" is where you configure the hostRules and pathMatchers.

[The Cloud Console should display two load balancers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNmwn.png)

Creating one url map for the HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection and host rules might work but it is not the recommended way.